# Connect Tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, database-design

I'm attempting to connect two tables in MySQL so that when selected, a value is pulled from the table.

Table 1

```
id
mobile_car
```

Table 2

```
id
mobile_car
car_domain
```

When the mobile_car is selected via a dropdown and the user registers this, I would like to be able to have it connect to the car_domain so I can call this later in the application.

For example, if the user selects "Verizon" as their mobile_car, I would like it to link to the car_domain "@vtext.com" so I can connect their phone number with the car_domain. Essentially, I'm sending a text by way of emailing their cell number.

I know there are programs and pre-built options, but I'd like an understanding of how this could be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try joining your two tables together:

```
SELECT t1.mobile_car, t2.car_domain
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.mobile_car = t2.mobile_car
```

I'm also assuming that your actual table structure will be more complex than this, since right now you can actually just query Table 2 by itself to get what you need.